# Plugin WooCommerce Checkout de evanto

Tags: wordpress, plugin, checkbox

he adquirido un plugin de `Evanto`, para añadir campos tipo select a mi tema de wordpress en el checkout. Ahora me enfrento a varios problemas:

1. No puedo acceder al soporte técnico del plugin debido a que no me llega el correo de confirmacion de email.
2. No sé como configurar correctamente el plugin, ya que no me aparecen los campos que incluyo ni me aparecen en las facturas ni en las órdenes.

Adjunto algunas capturas para que veais como va:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al final no he encontrado solucion,... puede que sea un error del tema que no coge bien los campos o plugin o otra cosa.. en cualquier caso he optado por devolver el plugin ya que el funcionamiento no era el correcto y el soporte técnico tampoco ha sido de gran ayuda.